# Jquery adding items to a list without reloading page

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, forms, user-interface

I'm pretty stuck on how this should be achieved, mostly down to my lack of javascript knowledge. This is the code I'm looking at:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/VrGau/

What I'm trying to do is have it so a user can type add a "responsibility" in the responsibility field, then click add and have it appear in a list above it. The user can do this for up to 10 responsibilities.

The result would look something like this:

```
**Responsibility List:**

 - Added responsibility 1
 - Added responsibilty 2

*responsibility field - add button*
```

Can anyone explain how this should be done, it seems like it would have to involve ajax. I would really appreciate some more information or even an example.

Thank you.

**EDIT:** Here is a little bit more clarification. I want this data to be sent to the server as a list of items. I have seen examples of this being implemented, and here is a screenshot:[image]

The user types in something in the text box, then clicks "add" and then it appears in a list above it. This information is what is submitted to the server.

Comment: First of all, here's a way how you can add items to your "list" (which is a textarea in your case tbh). http://jsfiddle.net/VrGau/2/ You might want to use a disabled `select` element instead, so you can easily count the existing children without much trouble...

Comment: You want have a form that the number of textfield to type responsibility can be dynamically added when they click add button?

Comment: I think I haven't explained myself well. I want to use a text area to add items to a list, which is then submitted as part of the form. The "add" button to the side of the field add the text area value to the list.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe this one can help also, this limits only 10 list

```
var eachline='';
$("#send").click(function(){
   var lines = $('#Responsibilities').val().split('\n');
   var lines2 = $('#Overview').val().split('\n');
   if(lines2.length>10)return false;
   for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
      if(lines[i]!='' && i+lines2.length<11){
       eachline += '- Added ' + lines[i] + '\n';
      }    
   }
   $('#Overview').text(eachline);
   $('#Responsibilities').val('');  
});
```

Try it here
http://jsfiddle.net/markipe/ZTuDJ/14/

Answer (score 1):

Something like that maybe?

http://jsfiddle.net/VrGau/10/

```
var $responsibilityInput = $('#responsibilityInput'),
    $responsibilityList = $('#responsibilityList'),
    $inputButton = $('#send'),
    rCounter = 0;

var addResponsibility = function () {
    if(rCounter < 10){
        var newVal = $responsibilityList.val()+$responsibilityInput.val();
        $responsibilityList.val(newVal+'\n');
        $responsibilityInput.val('');
    }
}

$inputButton.click(addResponsibility);
```

Comment: Thank you for the help but this isn't quite right. I have tried to improve my question with more clarification

Comment: Actually I think this answer is close but it puts it in the text box not above it

Answer (score 0):

Add id for textarea fields

```
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="Responsibilities"  id="resplist"></textarea>Add responsibility<br />
<textarea rows="4" cols="50" placeholder="How to apply" id="inputresp"></textarea>
```

You need Jquery. Use this js code

```
var i=0;
$("#send").click(addresp);
function addresp()
{
    if (i<10)
    {
        $("#resplist").val($("#resplist").val()+$("#inputresp").val()+'\n');
        $("#inputresp").val("");
        i++;
    }
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/br0nsk1y/bDE9W/

Comment: Thank you for your reply. I have tried to edit my initial post to explain between what I am after. Your code seems to add details into the text area, whereas really the text area is used just to type in the value and then when the "add" button is clicked, the value from the field appears above it in a list format. This is what is submitted to the server.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on if you want to post data to the server or not. If only in the client side you can do like this.

```
$("#send").on("click", function(event){
    if($("#list li").size() < 10){
        $("#list").append("<li>" + $("#responsibilities").val() + "</li>");
    }
});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/VrGau/7/

Comment: Thank you for your help, but I do want it sent to the server. I have updated my question with more information and hopefully clarification.