# Add items to a list using jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I had a quick question that I can't figure out. I am working with this code:

http://jsfiddle.net/spadez/ZTuDJ/32/

```
// If JS enabled, disable main input
$("#responsibilities").prop('disabled', true);
// $("#responsibilities").addClass("hidden");

// If JS enabled then add fields
$("#resp").append('<input placeholder="Add responsibility" id="resp_input" ></input><input type="button" value="Add" id="add"> ');

// Add items to input field
var eachline='';
$("#add").click(function(){
    var lines = $('#resp_input').val().split('\n');
    var lines2 = $('#responsibilities').val().split('\n');
    if(lines2.length>10)return false;
    for(var i = 0;i < lines.length;i++){
        if(lines[i]!='' && i+lines2.length<11){
        eachline += lines[i] + '\n';
        }    
    }

        $('#responsibilities').text($("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text() );

    $('#resp_input').val('');
});
```

The idea is that you type something in the responsibility field and it gets inserted into a text area. What I also want to do is that when an item is inserted into the text area it also prints it out above it in a list format like this:

`<li>inserted item 1</li> <li>inserted item 2</li>`

I'm really new to javascript but this was my best stab at it based on information found online:

```
$("#resp").append('<li> +eachline </li> ')
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$('#responsibilities').text($("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text() ).before("<li>"+lines+"</li>");
```

Demo `--->` http://jsfiddle.net/ZTuDJ/34/

Answer (score 1):

http://jsfiddle.net/pjdicke/ZTuDJ/35/

You will need to create a `<ul>` then add this below

```
$('#responsibilities').text( $("<div>" + eachline + "</div>").text() );

// add this line after above 
$('<li>' + lines + '</li>').appendTo('#list');
```

Answer (score 0):

I already fixed that for you in your previous question.

[Jquery adding items to a list without reloading page](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17167552/jquery-adding-items-to-a-list-without-reloading-page/17167940#17167940)

http://jsfiddle.net/blackjim/VrGau/15/

```
var $responsibilityInput = $('#responsibilityInput'),
    $responsibilityList = $('#responsibilityList'),
    $inputButton = $('#addResp'),
    rCounter = 0;

var addResponsibility = function () {
    if(rCounter < 10){
        var newVal = $responsibilityList.val()+$responsibilityInput.val();
        if(newVal.trim()!==''){
            var newLi = $('<li>');
            $('ul#respList').append(newLi.text(newVal));
            $responsibilityList.val('');
            rCounter+=1;    
        }
    }
}

$inputButton.click(addResponsibility);
```